can we get https one's url even we clone using `ssh` for the same git repo, looking for git command
here are my system details

Ubuntu 24.04
git v 2.43.0

usually, to check remote url from terminal, we write below command

git remote -v

and get below outout
git@github.com:<username>/<whatever>.git
which is correct as I do clone using SSH always and I want as it is BUT looking for any git command which gives the output in https because if we copy and paste in address bar then it does not open, for that we we need http/https one.
please note, I do not want to change origin from ssh to http
below is dummy code
> git remove -v -h
https://github.com/<username>/<whatever>

note: the both URL are denoting the same repo but just the protocol changes, both are should not be completely diffrent

I assume they downvote (I didn't) because they don't understand your question (I don't understand it too). If you want to also save the https URL why not adding a second remote with the URL? You don't have to make use of this remote via git. Or change and use Github via https url and access token.

so can we add 2 remote within a same repo?

How should Git know that two totally different URLs refer to the same repo? I don't think that there is a standardized way to translate a git ssh url to a git https url. The URLs are defined by github.

its not totally different at all; same url but instead of git@github, it must have https:, so that if we copy and paste in address bar it should work. and without changing ssh to https. can we add additional http url also?

That the URLs are pretty close is because Github decided to implement it that way. BTW: Why don't you simply try it yourself instead of asking?

@Robert Thanks for suggestion; I do ask the question after trying and not getting succeed. Always.

Set a global configuration option.
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf https://github.com/

Use the https url to clone the repository.
git clone https://github.com/foo/bar.git

Affected by the configuration option and its value, the real url is converted to git@github.com:foo/bar.git. git remote -v also shows the result.
The original https url is recorded in the configuration option remote.origin.url. Run git config remote.origin.url to get the value.
Create an alias to make it shorter.
git config --global alias.http "config --get remote.origin.url"

The alias command git http prints https://github.com/foo/bar.git.

documentation of git url.<base>.insteadOf

